# Grouping by secondary dataframe

Tags: r, grouping

I have two data frames that have a structure similar to the one here in the example:

```
types=data.frame(t(data.frame(A=sample(c("T1", "T2"), 20, replace = TRUE), B=sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 20, replace=TRUE))))

num_df=data.frame(replicate(20,sample(0:1,30,rep=TRUE)))

> types
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
A T2 T2 T2 T1 T1 T2 T2 T1 T1  T2  T2  T2  T1  T1  T1  T2  T1  T1  T1  T2
B  A  B  B  C  B  D  D  A  B   D   C   D   A   A   C   C   A   A   D   B

> head(num_df)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1
2  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
5  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
6  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
```

Each column of "types" refers to a column of num_df.
I need to obtain another data frame where I average the columns of num_df by using the variables in types.  For instance, I want to obtain the average of all the columns of num_df where types are "T1" and "A" (and then continue for all the other combinations).

A possible way to do this would be by using a couple of for loops and changing the various variable in the quotes like:

```
rowMeans( num_df[, colnames(num_df)[types[1,]=="T1" & types[2,]=="A"] ])
```

But I think there is a more elegant solution.  Maybe using dplyr?  group_by?

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Why did you ask this twice?

Comment: Connection problems, it seemed to me that my first submission didn't work... Sorry.
I am going to delete one of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this could help

```
as.data.frame(
  lapply(
    split.default(types, do.call(paste, asplit(types, 1))),
    function(v) rowMeans(num_df[names(v)])
  )
)
```

which gives output like

```
        T1.A T1.B      T1.C      T1.D T2.A T2.B      T2.C T2.D
1  1.0000000  0.0 0.8333333 0.3333333    1    1 0.6666667    0
2  0.0000000  0.0 0.6666667 0.3333333    0    0 0.3333333    0
3  0.3333333  0.5 0.6666667 0.6666667    1    0 0.3333333    1
4  0.3333333  0.5 0.3333333 0.3333333    1    0 0.6666667    0
5  0.6666667  0.5 0.5000000 1.0000000    0    1 0.6666667    0
6  0.3333333  0.5 0.3333333 0.3333333    0    0 0.6666667    1
7  0.0000000  1.0 0.5000000 0.3333333    0    1 0.6666667    0
8  0.6666667  0.5 0.8333333 0.6666667    1    0 0.3333333    1
9  0.6666667  0.0 0.6666667 0.6666667    1    0 0.6666667    0
10 0.0000000  0.5 0.3333333 1.0000000    0    1 0.6666667    1
11 0.0000000  0.5 0.5000000 0.0000000    1    1 0.6666667    1
12 0.3333333  0.5 0.1666667 0.6666667    1    1 1.0000000    1
13 0.3333333  0.5 0.3333333 0.6666667    0    0 0.3333333    0
14 1.0000000  0.5 0.5000000 0.6666667    0    1 0.6666667    1
15 0.3333333  0.5 0.3333333 1.0000000    1    1 0.6666667    0
16 0.6666667  0.5 0.8333333 0.0000000    1    0 0.6666667    1
17 0.0000000  0.5 0.3333333 0.0000000    0    1 0.6666667    1
18 0.3333333  0.0 0.3333333 0.6666667    0    0 0.6666667    0
19 0.6666667  1.0 0.5000000 0.3333333    0    0 1.0000000    0
20 0.6666667  1.0 0.5000000 0.3333333    1    0 0.3333333    0
21 1.0000000  0.5 0.1666667 0.6666667    1    1 0.3333333    0
22 0.3333333  0.5 0.1666667 0.6666667    1    1 0.3333333    0
23 0.0000000  0.5 0.5000000 0.6666667    0    0 0.3333333    1
24 1.0000000  0.5 0.3333333 0.0000000    0    1 0.6666667    0
25 1.0000000  0.5 0.6666667 0.3333333    1    0 0.3333333    0
26 0.6666667  0.5 0.3333333 0.3333333    1    0 0.6666667    0
27 0.3333333  0.5 0.3333333 0.6666667    1    1 0.6666667    1
28 0.0000000  1.0 0.6666667 0.6666667    0    0 0.0000000    1
29 0.6666667  0.5 0.5000000 0.3333333    0    0 0.3333333    1
30 0.6666667  0.5 0.6666667 0.3333333    0    0 0.3333333    0
```

Comment: It is an absolutely great answer.  Yes, it does help.  Just adding "as.data.frame" I think I get the result I want.

Comment: And change rowSums with rowMeans.